# About of original raw data and intermediate data has been transformed

Tags: data-science, project-structure, cookiecutter

I want to use the Cookiecutter Data science project structure, to my project. I found http://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/ 
and it looks great.

I am analyzing the directory differences on their structure and I have some question related to the different data stages. In the `README.md` file [setup the difference between external, interim, processed and raw data.](http://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/#directory-structure)

```
 ├── data
    │   ├── external       <- Data from third party sources.
    │   ├── interim        <- Intermediate data that has been transformed.
    │   ├── processed      <- The final, canonical data sets for modeling.
    │   └── raw            <- The original, immutable data dump.
```

I am working on a project, in which the data is originated from sensors and is managed via a web application dashboard. Additionally, I have been performing some JOINS on SQL database dump in the order to extract other  data that I need to start to work with.

What is the difference between raw data and external data?
The data which I describe the extract process above or the way in how do I get them to make that they are to be cataloged like raw data?

Why aren't these considered like external data?

These will be considered external data whether I get them from other sources different to my organization which owns of the sensors and web application dashboard data administration?

**About of raw data**
They make approach especially to:

> Don't ever edit your raw data, especially not manually, and especially not in Excel. Don't overwrite your raw data. Don't save multiple versions of the raw data. Treat the data (and its format) as immutable. The code you write should move the raw data through a pipeline to your final analysis

I understand this, and it is a best practice :)

To illustrate my question, I want to select some indexes from one dataset sample which I am working:

I read some raw dataset which I extract using SQL joins. **The data are changed**

Then, these are my raw data:

```
# I read some raw dataset
data = pd.read_csv('fruit-RawData.csv')
data.head()


    weight  date                number  lat      lng          farmName
0   3.09    2012-07-27 07:08:58     15   57.766231 -16.762676   Totti
1   1.50    2012-07-27 07:09:01     15  57.766231 -16.762676    Totti
2   10.50   2012-07-27 07:09:02     15  57.766231 -16.762676    Totti
3   2.50    2012-07-27 07:09:04     15  57.766231 -16.762676    Totti
4   6.50    2012-07-27 07:09:06     15  57.766231 -16.762676    Totti
```

If I select only the weight, date and number ...

```
data = data[['weight','date','number']]
data.to_csv('fruits.csv', sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

And I get:

```
    weight  date               number
0   23.09   2012-07-27 07:08:58 5
1   30.50   2012-07-27 07:08:58 5
2   19.50   2012-07-27 07:08:58 5
3   25.50   2012-07-27 07:08:58 5
4   26.50   2012-07-27 07:08:58 5
```

These data subset could be considered like intermediate data which has been transformed, or still are raw data?

I unknow if these questions are valid.

Comment: **External data** is data that is created, generated or collected outside of the organization. If I or my organization is collecting the data from the sensors (regardless of who owns the sensors) then it’s not considered 3rd party data. If an outside organization is using the sensors to collect the data and then they transmit the data over to you, then **it’s 3rd party data.**

Comment: JOINS on SQL database dump with the order to extract other features or data are considered **Interim data**. `fruit-RawData.csv` are **raw data** and `fruits.csv` are **interim data**

Comment: [Issue #136 Clarify difference in function between data/external and data/raw](https://github.com/drivendata/cookiecutter-data-science/issues/136) has a discussion on how to think of raw/external.